# Surly Pugsley bottom bracket replacement

Tags: bottom-bracket, compatibility, replacement, fatbike

Does the bottom bracket on Surly Pugsley need to be replaced with a like for like  surly part (100mm external bottom bracket) or will any 100mm external bottom bracket be compatible..?

The surly part is quite expensive compared to some other brands, but I can't be certain that they are compatible with the Surly O.D. crank.

First time doing this job, apologise for any ignorance.

Appreciate any insight.

Answer (score 1):

Surly O.D cranks have a standard (for threaded external BB bearings) 24mm spindle diameter, and the outboard bearing units seem to be standard width (unlike the extra wide Surly Moonlander specific variant. I think you are safe with a non Surly 100mm BB.

Answer (score 0):

The updated (orange) Pugsley [uses](https://surlybikes.com/bikes/pugsley/bike_specs) Race Face bottom bracket compatible with AEfect cranks. I am not sure which exact model is used.

The legacy (green) Pugsley [uses](https://surlybikes.com/bikes/legacy/pugsley/pugsley_green/bike_specs) SRAM GXP bottom bracket compatible with the SRAM GXP crankset, which is 24mm on the right side but 22mm on the left side.